# C# .net Offline page?

Tags: c#, html, razor, offline-caching

So I have here a .NET C# web app that needs one page able to be viewed offline as a user could be off in the middle of *'whoop whoop'* with no internet.

The order of events are:

1. User visits a form online
2. Store the webpage using HTML5 so they can visit it later offline
3. When online - the user then can submit the form to the database

I've been looking over [HTML5 appcache](http://html5doctor.com/go-offline-with-application-cache/) however it seems to only reference physical .html or .php pages rather than storing pages which have been generated by 'Razor' .cshtml Views.
e.g. **domain.com/path/view**.
I haven't been able to find any relevant documentation for my problem either.

So is it possible to cache a .NET webapp ofline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have not tried it, and assuming your app uses ASP.NET MVC, this might help you:
[Build an HTML5 Offline Application with Application Cache, Web Storage and ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codemag.com/Article/1112051)

It uses HTML5 Offline Web Application API (or HTML Application Cache). Note the comment on browser support.

The linked article shows a sample application, but I could not see a link to a downloadable source code. But one commenter appears to have recreated the project.

Comment: Came across this site recently while researching but skipped over it as it seems to have a lot of information repeated elsewhere. If it's helpful to me I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Basically, you need the page you want offline to have `<html manifest="{manifest_name}">`, and that manifest file defines which related resources are accessible offline, or online only. So with MVC, you can use a different layout.cshtml for pages you want to be available offline. Or in the case of the linked article, the View has no layout page, and instead has the `html` tag with the manifest attribute.

Comment: hrmm it seems to not like the manifest MIME type. Getting a **AppCache Fatal Error** in IE, **Application Cache Error event: Failed to parse manifest** in Chrome and **Application Cache manifest had an incorrect MIME type: text/html** in Safari. Almost bashing my head upon the table at this point :(.

Comment: Your manifest should be served with mime type "text/cache-manifest". You can check the [section "What to configure in IIS" in this blog](http://blog.christian-heindel.de/2011/10/23/how-to-host-html5-offline-web-applications-on-an-iis-web-server/)

Answer (score 0):

The appcache is what you need. Note that you specify the pages to be cached, but the browser never sees if the page is a static .html or generated via Razor. As long as the path you specify opens the right page, it will be cached.

Comment: can you post an example or relevant documentation?